# How may I override the compiler (GCC) flags that setup.py uses by default?

Tags: python, gcc, setuptools, setup.py, distutils

I understand that `setup.py` uses the same `CFLAGS` that were used to build Python. I have a single C extension of ours that is segfaulting. I need to build it **without** `-O2` because `-O2` is optimizing out some values and code so that the core files are not sufficient to pin down the problem.

I just need to modify `setup.py` so that `-O2` is not used.

I've read `distutils` documentation, in particular `distutils.ccompiler` and `distutils.unixccompiler` and see how to add flags and libs and includes, but not how to modify the default GCC flags.

Specifically, this is for a legacy product on Python 2.5.1 with a bunch of backports (Fedora 8, yes, I know...). No, I cannot change the OS or Python version and I cannot, without great problems, recompile Python. I just need to build a one off of the C extension for one customer whose environment is the only one segfaulting.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

- Prepend `CFLAGS="-O0"` before you run `setup.py`:

  ```
  % CFLAGS="-O0" python ./setup.py
  ```

  The `-O0` will be appended to `CFLAGS` while compiling, therefore will override previous `-O2` setting.
- Another way is add `-O0` to `extra_compile_args` in `setup.py`:

  ```
  moduleA = Extension('moduleA', .....,
          include_dirs = ['/usr/include', '/usr/local/include'], 
          extra_compile_args = ["-O0"], 
          )
  ```
- If you want to remove all default flags, use:

  ```
  % OPT="" python ./setup.py
  ```

Comment: when i run with the above setting, it shows both CFlaGS, -O2 as well as -O0. it is not overriding it

Comment: @Sagar For compilers such as gcc and clang, the later flag takes precedence, so if `-O0` appears on the command line after `-O2`, then `-O0` is overriding it.

Comment: Note that [compiler/linker environment variables are ignored on Windows](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/4b64119ab29b1418dc4975ea4212ab38f112c2ab/setuptools/_distutils/sysconfig.py#L184).

Comment: `OPT` doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure @EvgenKo423?

Comment: @matanster Yeah, I tried it myself and the link above shows how it really works. Note that I'm talking about environment variables only.
I mean they are ignored by Python that is, but the compiler itself will of course use its variables if you'll set them. You just can't use `CFLAGS` to modify MSVC flags on Windows.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this problem when I needed to fully remove a flag (-pipe) so I could compile SciPy on a low-memory system. I found that, as a hack, I could remove unwanted flags by editing /usr/lib/pythonN.N/_sysconfigdata.py to remove every instance of that flag, where N.N is your Python version. There are a lot of duplicates, and I'm not sure which are actually used by setup.py.

Comment: This did the trick as a work around...Just had to edit the CFLAGS entry

Answer (score 4):

`distutils`/​`setuptools` allows any compiler/​linker flags to be specified with `extra_compile_args`/​`extra_link_args` argument when defining a Python extension in `setup.py` script. These extra flags will be added after default ones and will override any mutually exclusive flags present earlier.

For regular use, however, this is not much useful as a package you distribute through PyPI can be built by different compilers having an incompatible options.
The following code allows you to specify these options in extension- *and compiler*-specific way:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext


class build_ext_ex(build_ext):

    extra_compile_args = {
        'extension_name': {
            'unix': ['-O0'],
            'msvc': ['/Od']
        }
    }

    def build_extension(self, ext):
        extra_args = self.extra_compile_args.get(ext.name)
        if extra_args is not None:
            ctype = self.compiler.compiler_type
            ext.extra_compile_args = extra_args.get(ctype, [])

        build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)


setup(
    ...
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext_ex},
    ...
)
```

Of course you could simplify it if you want all extensions to use the same (but still compiler-specific) options.

Here is a [list of supported compiler types](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/4b64119ab29b1418dc4975ea4212ab38f112c2ab/setuptools/_distutils/ccompiler.py#L964) (as returned by `setup.py build_ext --help-compiler`):

```
--compiler=bcpp     Borland C++ Compiler
--compiler=cygwin   Cygwin port of GNU C Compiler for Win32
--compiler=mingw32  Mingw32 port of GNU C Compiler for Win32
--compiler=msvc     Microsoft Visual C++
--compiler=unix     standard UNIX-style compiler
```

Comment: It's even compatible with Python 2.5. =))

Comment: Could you possibly lay down the compatibility aspect or concerns that you have mentioned in a little more depth or breadh?

Comment: @matanster Your extensions could be built on Windows with MSVC or on Unix-likes with GCC. These compilers have different options, but `extra_compile_args` only allows you to specify a single set of options, so you have to use the code above or something else to overcome this inconvenience.