# Remove all default compiler arguments in setup.py

Tags: c++, python, build, distutils

I am building an extension module with distutils, which unfortunately calls the compiler with a bunch of arguments that I do not want.
Specifically, it uses the `CFLAGS` variable defined in /usr/lib64/python2.7/config/Makefile, and which is also returned by

```py
>>> from distutils import sysconfig
>>> print(sysconfig.get_config_vars()['CFLAGS'])
-fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv   -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv
```

The answer given to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928110/how-may-i-override-the-compiler-gcc-flags-that-setup-py-uses-by-default) doesn't work; setting `CFLAGS=""` from the command line causes gcc to be called with

```sh
-DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv
```

as if `OPT` was empty in the makefile, but actually setting `OPT=""` has no effect.
Is there any way to to tell distutils to not add these flags?
I know that I can override most of these by adding my own flags (manually undefining macros like `-DNDEBUG` with `-UNDEBUG` and overriding `-O2` with `-O0`), but that's really ugly and there definitely should be a better way.

Comment: I would in particular like to remove the -Wp flag, which prevents ccache from getting direct hits (see http://ccache.samba.org/manual.html#_troubleshooting).

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem that setting `OPT` and `CFLAGS` had no effect. It seems as though [other builds](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=727364) also have this problem, and it is a [Distutils bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue21121).

This is not by any means a satisfactory solution and isn't any less ugly than what you suggest, but I was able to finally disable these flags and get my extension to build by modifying `python/distutils/sysconfig.py`. I inserted a few lines into the `customize_compiler` function (starting at line 206 for my install)

Old

```
    if 'LDFLAGS' in os.environ:
        ldshared = ldshared + ' ' + os.environ['LDFLAGS']
    if 'CFLAGS' in os.environ:
        cflags = opt + ' ' + os.environ['CFLAGS']
        ldshared = ldshared + ' ' + os.environ['CFLAGS']
```

New

```
    if 'LDFLAGS' in os.environ:
        ldshared = ldshared + ' ' + os.environ['LDFLAGS']
    if 'OPT' in os.environ:
        opt = os.environ['OPT']
    if 'CFLAGS' in os.environ:
        cflags = opt + ' ' + os.environ['CFLAGS']
        ldshared = ldshared + ' ' + os.environ['CFLAGS']
```

This will at least allow you to completely overwrite the default `OPT` arguments with your own. It will most likely be necessary to add back in those arguments that were not causing a problem.

For example, for my own project I compile with

```
$OPT="-DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3" CFLAGS="-march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4" python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```