# Compile and use python-openzwave with open-zwave in non-standard location

Tags: python, c++, z-wave

I manually compiled [python-openzwave](https://github.com/OpenZWave/python-openzwave) to work with [C++ library](https://github.com/OpenZWave/open-zwave).

I would like to use it as Kodi addon (OpenELEC running on Pi 3), so can not use standard installation.
I've compiled everything, downloaded missing `six` and `louie` libs, and now try to run `hello_world.py`.

My current dirs structure is the following:

```
- root
  - bin
      - .lib
      - config
        Alarm.o
        ...
        libopenzwave.a
        libopenzwave.so
        libopenzwave.so.1.4
        ...
  - libopenzwave
      driver.pxd
      group.pxd
      ...
  - louie
      __init__.py
      dispatcher.py
      ...
  - openzwave
      __init__.py
      command.py
      ...
  six.py
  hello_world.py
```

But when I run hello_world.py, I get the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello_world.py", line 40, in <module> 
    from openzwave.controller import ZWaveController 
  File "/storage/.kodi/addons/service.multimedia.open-zwave/openzwave/controller.py", line 34, in <module> 
    from libopenzwave import PyStatDriver, PyControllerState 
ImportError: No module named libopenzwave
```

If I move `libopenzwave.a` and `libopenzwave.so` to root folder, then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello_world.py", line 40, in <module> 
    from openzwave.controller import ZWaveController 
  File "/storage/.kodi/addons/service.multimedia.open-zwave/openzwave/controller.py", line 34, in <module> 
    from libopenzwave import PyStatDriver, PyControllerState 
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initlibopenzwave)
```

What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: Are you sure that your module has initialization info, as said here: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function ?

Comment: Manually compiled how exactly? Not finding `initlibopenzwave` is caused, if I am not mistaken, by the `Cython` files not being `cythonized` and compiled correctly (`Cython` takes care of creating the `init<modulename>` functions for you. Could you elaborate on the compilation process?

Comment: @Jim, I've downloaded the source https://github.com/OpenZWave/python-openzwave/raw/master/archives/python-openzwave-0.3.1.tgz, unpacked it and run `make build`. This version doesn't require `Cython` in accordance with this discussion - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-openzwave-discuss/Yrgf-Xg5XRk.

Comment: @ShamilKMuhammed, that is not my module, but as I can see `libopenzwave.cpp` has `initlibopenzwave` function.

Comment: The only case where I see the `.pyx` files getting built is during `setup-lib.py` which is run when `sudo make install` (or when `sudo make install-lib`) is executed. I just get a lovely segfault on `import` now.

Comment: `libopenzwave` has been generated so indeed there does not seem to be a need to use `Cython` (for `cythonizing` the file). You do need to build the generated file and I don't think `make build` does that. It just builds `openzwave` and not the `Python` extention for it.

Comment: @Jim, thanks (never worked with C++ libs from Python before). What is the command to build `.pyx` files? Looking at `setup-lib.py` I can not find it.

Comment: `sudo make install` will call `setup-lib.py` for you automatically. It is going to use the default `Python` install directory for installations.

Comment: @Jim, this is the problem - since I am going to use that as OpenELEC/Kodi addon, I can not use standard `make install`. I should cross compile everything on Ubuntu, then use the archive on OpenELEC without any `install` steps.

Comment: @LA_ ah, right. The only thing I can think of is compiling `libopenzwave.cpp` with `python setup-lib.py build_ext --inplace`. This will compile it *inplace* (creating the shared library in the `src-lib` folder) You could then try adding it in the folder you need to import it from. (I have no familiarity with `OpenELEC` fwi, I just have experience with `cython`).

Comment: @Jim, I just found another way to generate the .c file - http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html. The question now is how to cross compile it.

Comment: `Cython` will just compile `Python` code (or `Cython` code) to a `.c` or `.cpp` file for you. From there on you should compile it with a standard `C/C++` compiler; this is what `setup-lib.py` does for you (it compiles it to a shared object) with `python setup-lib.py build_ext --inplace`. I see `OpenELEC` is a `Linux` system so compiling on a system like `Fedora`, `Ubuntu`, and others might just be what's needed. Have you tried running the `setup-lib.py` script?

Comment: @Jim, if I try to run `python setup-lib.py build_ext --inplace` on Ubuntu (where I cross compile), then I get the following error - `openzwave/libopenzwave.a: error adding symbols: File in wrong format`.

Comment: @Jim, looks like I don't need to do anything with `Cython`.. `libopenwave.cpp` file which comes in the package I downloaded already has a comment that it is generated by Cython.

Comment: Just learned that there is one more file created - `libopenzwave.o` in the `build` folder. Not sure yet how to use it.

Comment: Yes, `Cython` is definitely not needed. The error with `setup-lib.py` is probably because `setup-lib.py` isn't being compiled in the same way as the rest of the files in `openzwave`. When running `make build` do you set some specific flags in order to get cross compilation?

Comment: @Jim, yes, I pass ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE values. Interesting moment - I tried to repeat my steps of manual installation on Ubuntu (without cross compilation) and when run the test python code, got 'segmentation fault' error. Strange, that I don't get the same error about missing init function.

Comment: @LA_ yes, same segfault here, don't know what causes it yet, it finds the `init` function in this case because you compile everything using the same flags. [You may override/provide flags to `setup-lib.py`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928110/how-may-i-override-the-compiler-gcc-flags-that-setup-py-uses-by-default) as another attempt.

Comment: @Jim, I've stopped my experiments and decided to work with open-zwave with C++ directly instead of Python. Could you please post something as the answer, so I will be able to accept it and give you a bounty ;).

Comment: @LA_ I added an answer. Either case, if you ever bump into this problem with `python-openzwave` again and have an interest in a more complete answer, I would gladly place the same bounty on this question to respark interest and probably get a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the steps required consist of calls to `make build` which handles building the `.cpp` files for openzwave and downloading all dependencies (including `Cython`); and `make install` which runs the `setup-api`, `setup-lib.py` (this setup script also creates the `C++` Python extention for openzwave), `setup-web.py` and `setup-manager.py`.

Since you cannot run `make install` as you specified and are instead using the archive they provide, the only other options for creating the python extention, after building the openzwave library with `make build`, is generating the `.so` files for it without installing to standard locations.

Building the `.so` for the cython extention in the same folder as the `Cython` scripts is done by running:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

This should create a shared library in `src-lib` named `libopenzwave.so` (it is different from the `libopenzwave.so` contained in the `bin/` directory) which contains all the functionality specified in the extention module. You could try adding that to the `libopenzwave` folder.

If you pass special compiler flags during `make build` for building the openzwave library you should specify the same ones when executing the `setup-lib.py` script. This can be done by specifying the `CFLAGS` before executing it (as specified [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928110/how-may-i-override-the-compiler-gcc-flags-that-setup-py-uses-by-default)) or else you might have issues like `error adding symbols: File in wrong format`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the description of the `python-openzwave`'s build from the question's perspective. Almost all the steps correspond to the root `Makefile`'s targets.

- **Prerequisites.** There are several independent targets with little to no organization. Most use Debian-specific commands.

  - Cython *is not needed if building from an archive* (details below)
- **openzwave C++ library** (`openzwave openzwave/.lib/` target).

  - Build logic: `openzwave/Makefile`, invoked without parameters (but with inherited environment).
  - Inputs: `openzwave/` subtree (includes `libhidapi` and `libtinyxml`, statically linked).
  - Outputs: `openzwave/.lib/libopenzwave.{a,so}`
  - Accepts `PREFIX` as envvar (`/usr/local` by default)

    - The only effect that affects us is: `$(PREFIX)/etc/openzwave/` is assigned to a macro which adds a search location for config files (`Options.cpp`): `config/` -> `/etc/openzwave/` -> `<custom location>`.
- **libopenzwave Python C extension module** (`install-lib` target - yes, the stock `Makefile` cannot just build it; the target doesn't even have the dependency on the library).

  - Build logic: `setup-lib.py`
  - Inputs: `src-lib/`, `openzwave/.lib/libopenzwave.a`
  - Outputs: `build/<...>/libopenzwave.so` - yes, the same name as `openzwave`'s output, so avoid confusing them

    - By default, **`openzwave` is linked statically with the module** so you don't need to include the former into a deployment
    - The module does, however, need the `config` folder from the library. It is included by the build script when making a package.
  - Contrary to [what Jim says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37897891/648265), *Cython is not needed to build from an archive,* the archive already includes the generated `.cpp`.
  - Now, the catch is: the module itself uses `pkg_resources` to locate its data. So you cannot just drop the `.so` and `config` into the currect directory and call it a day. You need to make `pkg_resources.get_distribution('libopenzwave')` succeed.

    - `pkg_resources` [claims to support](http://galaxy.readthedocs.io/en/master/lib/pkg_resources.html#package-resource-api) *"normal filesystem packages, .egg files, and unpacked .egg files."*
    - In particular, I was able to pull this off: make an `.egg` (`setup-lib.py bdist_egg`), unpack it into the current directory and rename `EGG-INFO` into `libopenzwave.egg-info` (like it is in `site-packages`). A `UserWarning` is issued if I don't specifically add the `.so`'s location into `PYTHON_PATH`/`sys.path` before importing the module.
- **`openzwave`,`pyozwman` and `pyozwweb` Python packages** (`install`)

  - these are pure Python packages. The first one uses the C extension module, others use the first one.
  - Build logic: `setup-api.py`,`setup-manager.py`,`setup-web.py`
  - Input: `src-*/`
  - Output:  (pure Python)
  - They only use `pkg_resources.declare_namespace()` so you're gonna be fine with just the proper files/dirs on `sys.path` without any `.egg-info`'s