# python setup.py - how to remove compiler option HP-UX

Tags: python, setup.py, hp-ux

I'm new to python, and try to compile python module in HP-UX 11.31.

```
% CC=gcc python setup.py build
unix
running build
running build_ext
building 'pygoldilocks' extension
gcc -DNDEBUG -O +z -DPYGOLDILOCKS_VERSION=1.0 
gcc: +z: not recognized ...
```

this produces '+z' not recognized.

How to solove it? Can I remove the option '+z'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How may I override the compiler (gcc) flags that setup.py uses by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928110/how-may-i-override-the-compiler-gcc-flags-that-setup-py-uses-by-default)

Comment: @hoefling Thanks. It couldn't solve it.