# python distutils: how to change default compiler flags for one Extension only

Tags: python, setup.py, distutils

I have `setup.py` defining two `Extensions` and I'd like to change default `CFLAGS` for one extension, but not for the other. I checked the official documentation https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension but it does not explain what I need. It does explain how to add extra compiler/linker flags thoiugh.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I would follow the recipe from [Python Extension Patterns](https://pythonextensionpatterns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/compiler_flags.html) and reset the `CFLAGS` before compiling the `Extensions` and then restore them while setting all of the compiler flags in each fo the `Extensions` separately from scratch.

Comment: That example makes no sense because `distutils` itself [gets the flags from config](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.4.0/Lib/distutils/sysconfig.py#L186) and `extra_compile_args` only gets appended to them, so you can't clear the default flags, only extend them. It's been like that even before 2014 when that example was created.

Comment: So it seems that the only valid approach would be to edit the config file for the extension in question, right?

Comment: There seems to be also a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10867041/1509695).